# how do i use a loop to change the values in a list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i have three arrays

```
a=np.random.randint(10,size=50)

b=np.random.randint(10,size=50)

c=np.arrange(0,0,50)
```

where c is a list of just zeros

and im trying to use a loop to fill c with the max value of a and b in each corresponding element for example if a had [2,3,7..] and b had [3,6,8..]
the list c would have [8,7,6,3,3,2..]

i had tried to use a while loop but it just produced errors

```
while 0<=n<=50
 c[n]=max[a,b]
```

im new to code and any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

The first correction is to the way how you create *c* array.

`c=np.arrange(0,0,50)` creates an **empty** array (of size *0*).

If you want to create a list of *50* zeroes, you can use e.g.
`c = np.zeros(50, dtype=int)`.

Then let's look at your code:

As I suppose, writing `max[a,b]` you attempt to call *max* function
on the respective elements of *a* and *b* arrays.

The first error is that around parameters you should use **round**
(instead of square) brackets.

The second error is that your loop should have an index (the number of
the current element), so instead of *while* loop you should write:

```
for i in range(50):
```

and then use *i* in this loop:

```
for i in range(50):
    c[i] = max(a[i], b[i])
```

But more concise code would be without any loop. Just call:

```
c = np.maximum(a, b)
```

Without initial creation of an empty *c* array.

Note that here you refer the **whole** arrays and *Numpy* is clever enough
to "convert" it to a relevant loop, running over each element of both arrays.

The result is also a *Numpy* array, saved under *c* variable.

Note also that `np.max(...)` is a wrong choice here, as this function
computes maximum from a **single** array. See documentation of this function
for details.